# Format a numeric string using a numeric composite format

Tags: .net, asp.net

I've just encountered an interesting problem in a standard BoundField in a GridView.  The field is for `EmployeeCode`, which is purely numeric, but stored in a character column in the database.  The `DataFormatString="{0:00000}"` attribute on the BoundField doesn't work, as I assume that format is only for numeric values.

To work around this, I had to use a TemplateField, and bind the text value using the attribute `Text='<%# PadNumericString(Eval("EmployeeCode").ToString(), 5) %>'`.  Is there no simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting HtmlEncode = false on your original BoundField and use your existing dataformatstring.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work.  I ended up formatting the string in the DB view that populates the grid: "right('00000' + ar.EmployeeCode, 5) EmployeeCode"